# Null Graphics Context

Tags: ios, uigraphicscontext

Here is a code excerpt I am using:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^
{

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(irect.size, YES, 0.0 );
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    if (context == 0)
        NSLog (@"Null Graphics Context") ;
    else
        NSLog (@"OK") ;

    . . . .
    // Various drawing functions

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  }) ;
```

I am finding that every other call to UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext is returning NULL. I get this message on the console.

CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

What would cause UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext to return an invalid graphic context?

Comment: There is not enough info in your question. Have you checked out this one post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12424690/uigraphicsgetcurrentcontext-seems-to-return-nil

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As suggested by the comment, the answer is that the `CGRect` passed to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` has zero area. That apparently cases it to fail to create a graphics context.

Comment: I had the same issue and this was the answer, check if the width AND the height are not 0.