# "Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" - Posting Image To FaceBook

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, image, runtime-error

I am getting this message:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I realise that this is a common error and that there are many threads here relating to its probable source. I just don't know why I am getting the error message.

This error occurs when I press a 'FaceBook share' button - which takes a screenshot in-app and posts it to FaceBook. This is my code:

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI
import Social

class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate {

@IBAction func shareToFB(sender: AnyObject) {

    // Declare the snapshot boundaries
    let top: CGFloat = 70
    let bottom: CGFloat = 100

    // The size of the cropped image
    let size = CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height - top - bottom)

    // Start the context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size,true,0.0)

    // use context
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

    // Transform the context 
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -top)

    // Draw the view into the context (the snapshot)
    view.layer.renderInContext(context)
    let snapshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    // End the context 
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()


    let composeSheetFB = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
    composeSheetFB.addImage(snapshot)
    self.presentViewController(composeSheetFB, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

I have the identical code for Twitter sharing of the cropped image and it works with no error - with obvious reference changes re Twitter vs FaceBook.

If anyone can let me know what I'm doing wrong, much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: on which line you r getting crash ?

Comment: I believe its this line:    `let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!`

Answer (score 3):

According to Apple docs, you can only call `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` inside the `drawRect()` function in a `UIView()`, otherwise it returns nil, which is which the forceful unwrap throws an error.  Otherwise you will need to first push a valid context onto the stack manually using `UIGraphicsPushContext()`
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext

Hopefully that helps.

Edit:
Also asked here: [UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext seems to return nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12424690/uigraphicsgetcurrentcontext-seems-to-return-nil)

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look at those references. Seems odd that I have email, sms, twitter and other sharing using the same code that works error-free, but when it comes to FaceBook sharing, it trips up with a fatal error?